# How do password_verify() compares password and hashed password?

Tags: php

Does anyone have an idea about how the `password_verify()` function works? I've searched everywhere in the net about the said function  , but I never found a specific answer on how it compares its two parameters. Below is the proper syntax of the said function according to [php.net](http://php.net):

```
bool password_verify ( string $password , string `$hash` )
```

**The question is, does the function hashes the `$password` then compared it to $hash?** or

**It dehashed `$hash` instead then compare it with `$password`?**

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as "dehashing", so it seems that it would hash the password and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the entire point of a hash function is that it **cannot be reversed**, `password_verify` can't be using option 2.

That leaves option 1.

You can also look at [the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d3f8ca12a0b00f2a74a27424790222536235502/ext/standard/password.c#L314) where you can see that …

```
zend_string *ret = php_crypt(ZSTR_VAL(password), (int)ZSTR_LEN(password), ZSTR_VAL(hash), (int)ZSTR_LEN(hash), 1);
```

… it crypts the password and then …

```
/* We're using this method instead of == in order to provide
* resistance towards timing attacks. This is a constant time
* equality check that will always check every byte of both
* values. */
for (i = 0; i < ZSTR_LEN(hash); i++) {
    status |= (ZSTR_VAL(ret)[i] ^ ZSTR_VAL(hash)[i]);
}
```

… compares the hashed password (`ret`) with the hashed value passed in (`hash`)

Comment: This is a generic question. I thought when you hash two the same passwords results to different hashes? They say that everytime we a hash a string, it uses a unique salt?

Comment: PHP7> It Does generate a new Salt each time. But remember the Salt and the Cost parameters are all part of the resulting hash. These are then used to Hash the plain text password in that same way as the original. then the original hash and the new hash are compared

Comment: "I thought when you hash two the same passwords results to different hashes?" — Not always, hence why https://learncryptography.com/hash-functions/hash-collision-attack can work.

Comment: "They say that everytime we a hash a string, it uses a unique salt? — No. When you use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) "a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed" but random does not guarentee uniqueness.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as "dehashing". A hash is a one way function.

What `password_verify` actually does is, reading the salt and hashing function from the "hash", given by `password_hash` and then do exactly the same hashing again, with the given parameters.

Because of that, it's important to use `password_verify`, instead of just do something like `$hash == password_hash('...')`, as `password_hash` could use anothere hashing algorithm and creates each time a new random salt value. So calling `password_hash` with the same input multiple times on the same machine, would never return the same value.

Comment: Might be worth says specifically that `password_hash()`  WILL use a different Salt each time it is run. Thats one of its major benefits, in that it generates a GOOD Salt and a new one each time its run